# Is it possible in Javascript to set the state of a channel using PUBNUB?

Tags: javascript, state, channel, pubnub

I am currently making a word game where there can be a maximum lobby of four people. Then, the game will start. If someone joins when there is already 4 people, I force them to unsubscribe. However, if someone during a game leaves, I was thinking that I could say that the channel was "ingame" and do the same action using || in an if statement with what I currently use to kick people off for joining a full lobby. Is there a way to do this (or something similar/another solution which would solve my problem)?

Comment: Off the top of my head, if channel is full, you can prompt user if they want to get on wait list. If yes, then subscribe them to the -pnpres channel only to get presence events. On leave or timeout event, prompt user to join game. There's some other aspects that need to be considered here but that's a quick PubNub tip for you. Not sure what you mean about the "||" stuff though.

Comment: @CraigConover to simply ask my question (sorry for making it rather confusing, but thank you for the help), is there any way to set the state of the channel or set channel/server variables which can be accessed by all subscribers? My only current solution which I can think of is to change all the players' states to "ingame":"true" (or something like that) and check their states to determine whether the game is fit to join. Thank you for the help.

Comment: There is no *channel scope* state, only *user/channel scope* state. Soon, [PubNub BLOCKS](https://www.pubnub.com/products/blocks/) will allow you to create channel and app scope state. Is there any reason each client app can't just set their own state?